# Skype: Delete conversation with a bot

Tags: skype, bots

I added a skype bot and now I want to delete the complete chat history with that bot. If I remove the bot and add it again, the messages are all still there. There is also no option to delete the conversation.

I also removed all Skype-Data from my Android device, but the data seem to be online and reappeared.

How can I delete the data and completely start over?

Comment: Skype has documented the official process. Have you searched the internet before coming here?

Comment: @music2myear Yes I did, and your comment is not helpful. Do you have a link?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=skype+delete+conversation here are two articles from Skype.com, these will be the official how to's. If they do not work you'll need to contact Skype support.

Comment: This is the documentation for regular conversations with humans. But I'm aksing about a conversation with a skype chat bot.

Comment: You cannot. The bot is the other human, and unless they can be instructed to delete a conversation, you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to delete the conversation across all devices via web.skype.com. This option is missing on Android. 
Initially, the bot was not visible on web.skype.com, and I was not able to add it (bot is not published yet). I deleted the bot contact from Android Skype and readded it. Then it appeared on web.skype.com.

[image: context menu of bot contact]